# String array when assigned to an integer produces a weird value

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to figure out a code that a friend sent me and I couldn't figure out why this certain code exists.

The goal is that when you type a 3 digit number sequence in string, it converts it to int and prints the sequence in reverse.

```
string s;
cout <<"enter integer sequence";
cin >> s;
int firstdig, seconddig, thirddig;
firstdig = s[0];
seconddig = s[1];
thirddig = s[2];

cout << thirddig << seconddig << firstdig;
```

**Here is the problem with this code**

When I input "123", the output becomes "515049" instead of "321"

*However*

This is the code that apparently fixes the problem

```
string s;
cout <<"enter integer sequence";
cin >> s;
int firstdig, seconddig, thirddig;
firstdig = s[0] - '0';
seconddig = s[1] - '0';
thirddig = s[2] - '0';

cout << thirddig << seconddig << firstdig;
```

This time, I input "123", the output becomes "321"

My main question is, where did "515049" come from, and what does the code "- '0'" do?
I don't know what that code does. C++ C++ C++

Comment: 51, 50 and 49 are the ASCII values of '3', '2' and '1' respectively.  It follows that the ASCII value of '0' is 48, and that explains your second observation.

Comment: The digit varlables should be `char`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, you are converting a char into an int directly which, as it has been pointed out in the comments, gets the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of the characters.

In the second code, when you substract the ASCII value of the characters and '0' you get the original value of the character.